# browser close then open some times before closing completely when running a script with Selenium Ruby Webdriver

Tags: ruby, browser, selenium, webdriver

I got an issue when running a Selenium Ruby Webdriver script as below:

the browser is closed after Selenium finishes running my script (this is expected behaviour). However, right after, browser is reopen, and do nothing, then closed, continuously, the browser reopen then close. This thing repeats about 4 times before the browser (FF16, or IE9, or Chrome) is closed completely.

the below log messages are displayed everytime browser is opened and
closed. Note that I'm using @driver.quit to close the browser.
Please help guide me something I need to do to overcome this
inconvenient situation. Thanks so much.

```
*** LOG addons.xpi: shutdown
E*** LOG addons.manager: Application has been upgraded
*** LOG addons.xpi: startup
*** LOG addons.xpi: Skipping unavailable install location app-system-local
*** LOG addons.xpi: Skipping unavailable install location app-system-share
*** LOG addons.xpi: checkForChanges
*** LOG addons.xpi-utils: Opening database
*** LOG addons.xpi-utils: Creating database schema
*** LOG addons.xpi: New add-on fxdriver@googlecode.com installed in app-prof
*** Blocklist::_loadBlocklistFromFile: blocklist is disabled
*** LOG addons.xpi: New add-on {82AF8DCA-6DE9-405D-BD5E-43525BDAD38A} instal
in app-global
*** LOG addons.xpi: New add-on {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd} instal
in app-global
*** LOG addons.xpi: Updating database with changes to installed add-ons
*** LOG addons.xpi-utils: Updating add-on states
*** LOG addons.xpi-utils: Writing add-ons list
*** LOG addons.xpi: shutdown
*** LOG addons.xpi-utils: shutdown
*** LOG addons.xpi-utils: Database closed
*** LOG addons.xpi: startup
*** LOG addons.xpi: Skipping unavailable install location app-system-local
*** LOG addons.xpi: Skipping unavailable install location app-system-share
*** LOG addons.xpi: checkForChanges
*** LOG addons.xpi: No changes found
*** Blocklist::_loadBlocklistFromFile: blocklist is disabled
!!! error running onStopped callback: TypeError: callback is not a function
*** LOG addons.xpi: shutdown
E*** LOG addons.manager: Application has been upgraded
*** LOG addons.xpi: startup
*** LOG addons.xpi: Skipping unavailable install location app-system-local
*** LOG addons.xpi: Skipping unavailable install location app-system-share
*** LOG addons.xpi: checkForChanges
*** LOG addons.xpi-utils: Opening database
*** LOG addons.xpi-utils: Creating database schema
*** LOG addons.xpi: New add-on fxdriver@googlecode.com installed in app-prof
*** Blocklist::_loadBlocklistFromFile: blocklist is disabled
*** LOG addons.xpi: New add-on {82AF8DCA-6DE9-405D-BD5E-43525BDAD38A} instal
in app-global
*** LOG addons.xpi: New add-on {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd} instal
in app-global
*** LOG addons.xpi: Updating database with changes to installed add-ons
*** LOG addons.xpi-utils: Updating add-on states
*** LOG addons.xpi-utils: Writing add-ons list
*** LOG addons.xpi: shutdown
*** LOG addons.xpi-utils: shutdown
*** LOG addons.xpi-utils: Database closed
*** LOG addons.xpi: startup
*** LOG addons.xpi: Skipping unavailable install location app-system-local
*** LOG addons.xpi: Skipping unavailable install location app-system-share
*** LOG addons.xpi: checkForChanges
*** LOG addons.xpi: No changes found
*** Blocklist::_loadBlocklistFromFile: blocklist is disabled
!!! error running onStopped callback: TypeError: callback is not a function
*** LOG addons.xpi: shutdown
E*** LOG addons.manager: Application has been upgraded
*** LOG addons.xpi: startup
*** LOG addons.xpi: Skipping unavailable install location app-system-local
*** LOG addons.xpi: Skipping unavailable install location app-system-share
*** LOG addons.xpi: checkForChanges
*** LOG addons.xpi-utils: Opening database
*** LOG addons.xpi-utils: Creating database schema
*** LOG addons.xpi: New add-on fxdriver@googlecode.com installed in app-prof
*** Blocklist::_loadBlocklistFromFile: blocklist is disabled
*** LOG addons.xpi: New add-on {82AF8DCA-6DE9-405D-BD5E-43525BDAD38A} instal
in app-global
*** LOG addons.xpi: New add-on {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd} instal
in app-global
*** LOG addons.xpi: Updating database with changes to installed add-ons
*** LOG addons.xpi-utils: Updating add-on states
*** LOG addons.xpi-utils: Writing add-ons list
*** LOG addons.xpi: shutdown
*** LOG addons.xpi-utils: shutdown
*** LOG addons.xpi-utils: Database closed
*** LOG addons.xpi: startup
*** LOG addons.xpi: Skipping unavailable install location app-system-local
*** LOG addons.xpi: Skipping unavailable install location app-system-share
*** LOG addons.xpi: checkForChanges
*** LOG addons.xpi: No changes found
*** Blocklist::_loadBlocklistFromFile: blocklist is disabled
!!! error running onStopped callback: TypeError: callback is not a function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue happened because I have named some functions in a script with "test_" prefix. Just removing "test_" prefix from name of those functions, then the issue has been fixed.